# Problem with format () in an Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, format, deprecated

I'm trying to make an app in Electron js but the url doesn't load. The problem is in the format () function which appears strikethrough. It is apparently deprecated (*@deprecated -- since v11.0.0 - User the WHATWG URL API*). I need help!

```
...

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
});
```

Comment: Try this instead: `mainWindow.loadURL('file://./mainWindow.html')`

Comment: this throws 'not allowed to load local resource'

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was:

`mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'));`

What it does is basically return `"C:\__dirname\mainWindow.html"`